# animate 2 objects at the same time with jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do an animation. This animation consisting of a Button(glyphicon-plus-sign from Bootstrap) and a Box-Content with width:12% . when we click on the button, it rotates to negative direction and at the same time open the Box-Content width:40% with animate() which is custom animation from jQuery. Now my Problem is: i don't really know, how to return the Box-Content to the original width and at the same time rotate again the button to positive direction.
here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showNav(){
        $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('animate-open-button');
        $('.wrapper').animate({
            width:'40%'
        },{
            queue:false,
            duration:3000
        })
        $('nav ul li a').css('opacity','1');
    }

    function hideNav(){
        $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('animate-close-button');
        $('.wrapper').animate({
            width:'12%'
        },{
            queue:false,
            duration:3000
        })
        $('nav ul li a').css('opacity','0');
    }

    $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').on('click', function(){
        // if (hideNav()) {
            showNav();
        // }else{
            // hideNav();
        // }
    });
})
```

Some css style for the animation:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 12%;
}
nav ul li a{
  opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .80s ease;
}
.glyphicon-plus-sign.animate-close-button{
  animation: close linear 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation: close linear 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

  -moz-animation: close linear 3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;

  -o-animation: close linear 3s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;

  -ms-animation: close linear 3s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
@keyframes close{
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes close{
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes close{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes close{
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes close{
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.glyphicon-plus-sign.animate-open-button{
  font-size: 2.7em;
  animation: open linear 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation: open linear 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

  -moz-animation: open linear 3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;

  -o-animation: open linear 3s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;

  -ms-animation: open linear 3s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-225deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-225deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
         transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

@keyframes open{
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes open{
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes open{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes open{
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes open{
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
}
```

And here the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper container-fluid">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>          
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 main-nav">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">site1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">site2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">site3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">site4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you can see this animation better, to understand what I mean. Link: [jsfiddle/Mobile-navigation](https://jsfiddle.net/OliviaPanther34/33rhcyrr/) or here: [codepen.io/Mobile-navigation](http://codepen.io/Alanes/pen/NRpXOj) I appreciate very much every Help. thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for it, I realized that the hideNav() function was adding the class "animate-close-button" but wasn't removing the class "animate-open-button", because the toggleClass removes and adds the same class. So one option here might be adding a removeClass('animate-open-button') when hideNav() function triggers, like this:

```
function hideNav(){
    $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').removeClass('animate-open-button');
    $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('animate-close-button');
    ...
```

The same goes for the showNav():

```
function showNav(){
    $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').removeClass('animate-close-button');
    $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('animate-open-button');
    ...
```

And now on the click, we need to check weither the glyphicon has the "animate-open-button", or the "animate-close-button" class:

```
$('.glyphicon-plus-sign').on('click', function(){
    if ($('.glyphicon-plus-sign').hasClass('animate-open-button')) {
        hideNav();
    }else{
        showNav();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps,
Leo.

Comment: @OliviaP. I'm glad that it worked, could you mark the answer as correct please ? Good luck with the rest of the code !